# Getting column number from td

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Writing an extension for ***tablesorter***.. though its my first attempt at extending any js. I have a number of `<select>`s within a row of `<td>`s & need to know the column this td sits in.

When a value is changed in any of these selects e.g.

```
$('select').change(function(){

});
```

I need to get hold of the column this select is *sitting* in to set `col` for:

```
('tr.result > td:nth-child('+col+')').each(function(){
```

Is there a way I can get this from the td select is in?!?

--
solution for my specific problem was:

```
$('select').change(function(){

    td  = $(this).parent('td');

    col = $(td).parent().children().index(td);

});
```

Comment: Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `index()` function.

```
col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
```

Comment: Thanks- look about right, but i've tried a few variants on this, and all are returning -1. The only issue I can think of is that the table divides into <thead> & <tbody> but altering: .children('tbody'). doesnt help?

Comment: Yup you're right, of course you need the children of the parent (`TR`, not `TBODY` or `TABLE`)... see updated

Comment: Oh & just noticed the one other problem was that the 'this' in my question was select so solution is a slight variant. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear you know what's going on instead of just blindly copying the answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

> The cellIndex property returns the position of a cell in the cells collection of a table row.
>   [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp)

```
 td.cellIndex
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z577D/)

Comment: `cellIndex` is broken for tables using `colspan`. This means `cellIndex` might return different values for cells being on top of each other.